# Google Play Services not working

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm working on gps location app, my problem is that on my Galaxy S2 2.3.3(Gingerbread), GPS is not taking location. I have used Google Play Services(Revision 17). It's working on Samsung Galaxy s3 and S4(4.3). I have tried it by enabling setting for "Use wireless networks" but still not able to get success. It was working fine before but now it's not working.
what am I supposed to do to get rid of this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with your S2 try installing [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) app and see if gps works or not.
If no connectivity then check your cellphone not code ;)

Comment: Actually I have tried app on other devices also for resolutions 480X800, but still not getting success. It's working on S3 and S4, but what is the issue with s2?

Comment: GPS sensor might be damaged or due to some other reason might not be working properly :/

Answer (score 0):

Often this is because the device doesn't have google play services installed..

You can check if googlePlayServicesUtil is available like so:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        Log.e("PLAY SERVE", "status:" + status);
        try {
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 1).show();
            } else {
              //good to go
           }
```

This should also prompt the user to install it should it not be available on the device..  hope this helps

Comment: perhaps we could all benefit from you sharing your code